# Start using Java out of the box on Mac OS X

Tags: java, macos, installation

My 10.5.3 install on a MacBook doesn't seem to want to build [an example](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/essential/regex/test_harness.html) from Sun. It claims it can't find java.io.Console to import. This is annoying to me, and after much searching I can't figure out what I should do to fix it.

I have installed the Apple Developer Tools.

Here's what happens:

```
macbook:~ dlamblin$ javac RegexTestHarness.java
RegexTestHarness.java:32: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Console
location: package java.io
import java.io.Console;
               ^
RegexTestHarness.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class Console
location: class RegexTestHarness
        Console console = System.console();
        ^
RegexTestHarness.java:39: cannot find symbol
symbol  : method console()
location: class java.lang.System
        Console console = System.console();
                                ^
3 errors
```

Comment: What does javac -version show? Console is a Java 6 class.

Comment: Oh. now I feel silly it's javac 1.5.0_19. I guess I'll change the sample code to just use the System.console. I don't feel like installing 6 yet.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

mmyers already hinted at this, but it sounds like you've not upgraded to Java 6. You can get it from here: http://support.apple.com/downloads/Java_for_Mac_OS_X_10_5_Update_4

Comment: Thanks; I did need to do this AND drag it to the top of the list in the "Java Preferences" app.

Answer (score 3):

I assume you have already installed Java 6 on your machine, because [`java.io.Console`](http://www.stupidjavatricks.com/?p=43) is a Java 1.6 class. I have run into cases where I update OS X to Java 6, but when run from a command line, the older version is still used. This has happened even after adjusting the Java Preferences app (Applications > Utilities > Java Preferences).

Here is how I worked around it.

```
$ cd /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaVM.framework/Versions
$ sudo rm CurrentJDK
$ sudo ln -s 1.6.0 CurrentJDK
```